# Silverlight 5 - entity framework 5 and domain service exclude unsupported Geography type

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, geospatial, silverlight-5.0

I'm very new to Silverlight (this is my first test app) and I'm working through some walkthroughs on setting up a domain service for a silverlight 5 app that uses the Entity Framework.

I have a "TestApp1" project and a "TestApp1.Web" project which were generated when I created the Silverlight project.

I added an edmx model to the TestApp1.Web project and randomly picked a couple of tables out of a test db I have and one of them includes a Geography column (GeoLocation) which I see is now supported in EF5 (great!) but I'm getting an "unsupported type" error in my Silverlight project (TestApp1), how can exclude the GeoLocation property in my Domain Service so that my Silverlight App doesn't complain?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the table|column in the model itself - have you tried that? As well as the designer file too. Though you must be careful!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there's no way I'm going to start editing the edmx files manually, any changes get blown away everytime I update from the database. I've worked on a project where this caused many headaches...